# Objects do not appear on the screen when I put them in a loop

Tags: javascript

Yesterday I started using javascript p5 library. My problem is that when I write objects manually in draw() function - they appear on the screen and everything is fine, but when I put them in a loop, they do not appear.

```
function draw() {
   object[0].show();
   object[1].show();
   object[2].show();
   object[3].show();
}
```

this works fine.

```
for(var i = 0; i < objectsCreated; i++) {
    object[i].show();
}
```

this does not work.

```
this.show = function() {
    fill(this.color);
    rect(this.x, this.y, this.sizex, this.sizey);
}
```

this is my function for showing it.

Comment: And `objectsCreated` is of course `4`, and the loop is being called ?

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: In your for loop you need to have the condition be `I < objectsCreated.length`

Comment: @BrianShamblen still the same thing.

Comment: @haribo did you define the value of `objectsCreated` ?

Comment: @BrianShamblen OP never mentioned `objectsCreated` as an array or object. that was undefined

Comment: And it's still inside a `draw` function, right, as the P5 library calls that function

Comment: thanks for all of you! sorted this out. @adeneo

Comment: In the loop you'd need to use `objectsCreated[i].show();`

Answer (score 0):

You might be losing the context of `this` when you're looping through everything. It is unlikely that this is the issue but it might worth refactoring `this.show` so that its behavior is more predictable within the call stack.

Try this:

`this.show = () => {
    fill(this.color);
    rect(this.x, this.y, this.sizex, this.sizey);
};`